# How to apply a jQuery function to inline CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I've been putting together an animated stat circle counter using bits and bobs I've found. The circle has the numeric stat in the centre, and I've got this successfully counting up from zero when it runs.

```
<div class="single-circle">
  <h6 class="counter stat">50</h6>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 165 165" class="circle-svg">
    <g id="circles" data-name="circles">
      <circle class="back-circle" cx="82.5" cy="82.5" r="75" />
      <circle class="front-circle" cx="82.5" cy="82.5" r="75" style="stroke-dashoffset: -235px;" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$('.counter').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function () {
            $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
        }
    });
});
```

I'd now like to apply the same function to ".front-circle" by targeting the inline style selector "strokedash-offset", in order to have the circle animate alongside the numeric counter, but I'm struggling to achieve this.

Full JS Fiddle with SCSS here: https://jsfiddle.net/ch8phcbd/

Just to clarify, I'd like to target and manipulate the inline style selector's value in order to achieve this and avoid placing changeable values in the jQuery, as in the final version this value will be pulled into the view page dynamically.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was remove the css transitions so they don't affect the animation and on each step decremented the stroke-dashoffset of your red circle.

```
$('.counter').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function () {
            $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    var increase = Math.ceil(this.Counter);
    $(".front-circle").css("stroke-dashoffset", "-=2.5");
        }
    });
});
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ch8phcbd/4/

**UPDATE:**

In order to have more control over the counter we need to first find how many pixels the stroke-offset needs to be in order for the circle to be 100% red.
The number in your case is 472 which means that 1% of the circle is 4.72px.
We then need to make it increase the stroke-offset only once per number. Because the function is being called more than 50 times and is just rounding the numbers I've added an if statement to check if the number in the middle has changed since the last step and if so add 1% to the offset:

```
if(Math.ceil(this.Counter) > $this.text())
      {
        $(".front-circle").css("stroke-dashoffset", "-=" + singlePercent);
      }
```

If you change the number in `<h6 class="counter stat">50</h6>` you can see that it works for any percent.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ch8phcbd/10/

Comment: Thank you, this is great. However the amount that the first circle progresses is not reflective of the amount in the centre (50%). Looks to be going to about a third of the way. How would this be addressed? Also I'd like to target the inline style of the object class ".first-circle", rather than specify the amounts separately in the jQuery. The reason for this is that I'll be pulling in this data dynamically to the view page - in the final version this will be replaced with a variable. I will update the original post to better clarify this.

Comment: I didn't realize that it was meant to be a percentage. I made some changes to my answer and included a new js fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/vvkqmqLm/4/

Calculate offset and then apply it:

```
 var r = $circle.attr('r');
 var c = Math.PI*(r*2);

 (val < 0) { val = 0;}
 (val > 100) { val = 100;}

 pct = ((100-val)/100)*c;
```

also edited css so loading animation is clockwise

```
.circle-svg {
  transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1);
}
```

If you rewrite it slightly, you won't need to flip it horizontally (scaleX(-1)), but you get the idea.

Comment: The counter seems inconsistent. Out of five tries, it has stopped at 0, 50, 29, 49, and 17.

Comment: Can't recreate the issue. Works fine for me under Chrome, Opera and Firefox

Comment: This seems to be working backwards, in that the first-circle starts out at 100% and reduces to 50%, leaving the red half on the left as opposed to the right. Is this just me?